# Prevent PC from being powered off without first calling shutdown

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

I have a PC with windows 7. This computer runs a full-screen program at startup so users are unable to access the Desktop. Inside the program there is a button to shutdown the computer but users are not using this and turning off the system at the mains.

I am unable to use a UPS - as has been suggested - due to a ban on batteries at our location (explosives).

How can I protect Windows or prevent the computer from being turned off without first shutting down Windows using the correct shutdown procedure?

Comment: Remove the button. Glue in the PSU.. Not sure you can do what you want.. The only real solution I can think of is put the machine else where so it's only accessed by RDP

Comment: I use a computer in a entertainment system to show movie. But user turn this off without shutting down. So after a while windows become down. And i have to install or repair windows.

Comment: I want some solutions to protect windows about turn off without shutting down.

Comment: How do you expect to do this if some one can unplug it or pull the cable out?

Comment: Put in a UPS to provide power, setup the ups to do shutdown as soon as the power is pulled. Put the whole setup computer and ups in a "cage" (so it still gets air). disconnect the power switch and the reset switch, from the MB. Wire the PSU switch so it doesnt turn off.

Comment: Users cant see windows desktop. I mean a program runs on startup and users use this application to select movie and show it. They can just turn system off by a switch on main rack that disconnect main electric power to pc.

Comment: Thanks. But i cant use ups. Because i use it in explosion area and i cant use battery in this aera.

Comment: Can you update your question with precisely the specification you have and what you want... the answers you're going to get will be fairly general until your provide some detail as to what your scenario is, what you currently have and what you are capable of doing (i.e. you can't have UPS)

Comment: I have a pc with windows 7. This computer run a program in startup that user can not see windows desktop. Inside program there is a button to shut down system but users  do not use button and prefer turn system off by main electric power switch (disconnect electric power to pc).

Comment: So windows become down and I should repair or install windows. I want find a solution to protect windows against damage of "turn of without shutdown "

Comment: Ban of batteries, where is this.laptops have batteries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few precautions you can take to prevent people from simply "unplugging" or "switching off the socket" - cover the switch and hide/lock the cables away. You can get special PC cages that allow you to secure the computer and it can often be used to make sure people can't unplug the power from the rear of the computer. The other end of the power cable (the plug and wall socket end) is much more difficult. You could build a cabinet that you lock the PC away but also have the cabinet cover enough power sockets for you to power the PC and the monitor. Cut a hole just for the power button/any front ports you need access to (CD-ROM, USB etc.).

As @Dave pointed out his in his comment, you will need people to have access to the power button because if you want them to be able to shutdown the computer, then you'll also want them to be able to turn the computer on again the next day/whenever it's off and needs to be on - unless you make this a task ***you*** complete yourself, in which case you can lock the PC away and only you or authorised people can turn it back on again. even pressing and holding the power button will turn the PC off as if you'd pulled the plug - Windows will not have had chance to shutdown gracefully.

Without physically locking the computer (and the wall sockets) from general public access you'll never be able to solve your problem. Other solutions involve, as Dave else has pointed, more complex solutions such as using an RDP session but you will need a "dummy" machine to run the RDP client that connects to your "hidden away" computer. You could use a small version of Linux running from a read-only USB - it won't really matter if the machine is turned off without properly shutting down - the next boot will simply read from the CD or USB. You could put a script that whent he machine boots it runs an RDP client in fullscreen to your Windows box. The Windows box stays on and safe, the Linux machine can be turned on and off as often as you like.